# How do I calculate the uncertainty (error) of an oscilloscope measurement?

Tags: error-analysis

I currently have a lab report to write and nobody taught use how to calculate the error of our measurements with an oscilloscope could somebody explain it to me?
EDIT: We are measuring the Voltage Drop over the resistor and the Voltage over the Capacitor in an RC Circuit(R=1000(100) Ohm)(C=1.0(1)uF) . We exported this data (CSV) in order to fit the time constant of the exponential discharging process. The measurements are on the order of 10^-2 to 10^-4 Volts.

We used a Rigol ds1052e (it is a digital Multimeter)

This is the manual
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Users+Guide+DS1000E.pdf

EDIT:
DC Gain Accuracy:

2mV/div-5mV/div:
± 4% (Normal or Average acquisition mode) 
10mV/div-10V/div:
± 3% (Normal or Average acquisition mode)\

DC Measurement:
Accuracy, Average
Acquisition Mode
Average of ≥16 Waveforms with vertical position at zero:
± (DC Gain Accuracy× reading+0.1div+1mV)
Average of ≥16 Waveforms with vertical position not at zero:
± [DC Gain Accuracy× (reading+vertical position)+(1% of
vertical position) + 0.2div]
Add 2mV for settings from 2mV/div to 245 mV/div
Add 50mV for settings from 250mV/div to 10V/div

Is this the correct part in the manual for the calculation of the uncertainty in the voltage measurement?
If so is the following the correct way to calculate the uncertainty for a 72mV/div and a reading of 10mv and with an average acquisition mode greater than 16 Waveforms:
0.03 * 0.01V + 0.1 * 0.072 V+0.001V = 0.009 V (with rounding up)
Thx for the responses

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is a great place for physics questions and answers. Good answers require good questions. This question must be improved to get a good answer. Please specify what measurement you're talking about. An oscilloscope can be used to measure voltage, frequency, noise, and probably other things.

Comment: Thanks totally forgot to write what I am measuring with the oscilloscope :)

Answer (score 2):

Two main issues with a 'scope:

1. how well were you able to read the location of the trace on the screen? (you can probably manage 1/10 of a division, but people are not always careful)
2. how reliable is the calibration of the scope? The manufacturer's claims are a good resource for that, but often it is more accurate to compare the scope to another instrument which is known to be more accurate. e.g. a good signal generator and a digital multimeter.

After that you need to know standard theory of how to combine errors.

Comment: We exported the data to an csv so we got what the 8bit DAC thinks it measured. This means a resolution of 1/2^8 of the Fullscale (256 different levels) or do I is this a wrong assumption? I wasn't able to compare the scope with good signal generator so I cannot go this route. How would I go about finding the claims of the manufacturer exactly? how would it be written inside such an manual?

Comment: @xyhlon see chapter 5 _Specifications_ of the manual you linked to. Look for "accuracy" specs.

Answer (score 0):

Well no matter what experiment you do you have to use the gaussian error propagation (https://www.geol.lsu.edu/jlorenzo/geophysics/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html). So first you have to estimate your direct measuring errors realistically and then you have to use the gaussian error propagation to calculate the errors of the other variables with the error propagation. In the case of the oscilloscope you should have a reading uncertainty which has to be estimated and an intrinsic uncertainty of the machinery (the oscilloscope in this case) which should be written somewhere in the manual you send.

Comment: Thx for the response. The link to the gaussian error propagation isn't taking into account correlation of the variables which could decrease the uncertainty see(https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fehlerfortpflanzung#Generalisiertes_Fehlerfortpflanzungsgesetz , or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) german one is better

Comment: Are you telling me I should guess the measuring errors? I guess the reading uncertainty is the resolution of the DAC 8bits? Sorry for asking but I do not know where to find the intrinsic uncertainty of the oscilloscope inside the manual. English ain't my first language and I wouldn't know what to look for if it isn't called intrinsic uncertainty of an AC/ DC voltage measurement. Like with multimeter manuals.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy of scope measurements is not easy to determine because the scope manufacturers are deliberately vague. The core issue is the 8 bit resolution which is OK for a nice image but not suitable for actual laboratory measurements.

Noting that many measurements only a fraction of the full scale and there will be typically 3 LSB error for noise and offsets, this makes the effective resolution between 4-6 bits depending on how much of the screen is used. 4 bit resolution is an accuracy of 6% of reading.

For example, if you have a waveform with around +82Vpeak, you can't use the 20V/div so need to 50V/div, which means screen covers from -200V to +200V (full scale range of 400V). For that range the resolution is 400/250 = 1.6V/LSB. That means you are effectively measuring 82V with a system having a *resolution* of around 2V. Assume ±3 LSB for offset, noise and you are essentially measuring 82V ± 5V, which is very rough.

But this is just the start of the problem. Since the core is so rough, there is no point designing other parts of the system for "normal" accuracy. So for example the flatness of the frequency response in the pass band is usually designed for ±0.5dB which is equivalent to ±5% and this error is on top of the resolution/noise/offset.

There can also be errors in the software algorithms for rms measurements, and in HV probes and more.

And yet the manual says "DC gain error = ±3%" and does not give any hints at the many other sources of error. This is misleading, since there are no other numbers around, users (like me for many years) see the 3% and assume that is it.